# Can I determine the number of dimensions of a multi-dimensional list if it contains empty lists?

Tags: java, list, generics, multidimensional-array, casting

I have two classes `A` and `B` and a method `B convertAToB(A a)`. Now I want to make a method which converts multi-dimensional (or even single-dimensional) lists of `A` to `B`. For example:

- Given a `List<A>` it should return a `List<B>`
- Given a `List<List<A>>` it should return a `List<List<B>>`

and so on. My conversion method doesn't need to be fully type-checked by the compiler, for obvious reasons...the method will do the type-checking itself.

In the case where there are no empty lists anywhere in the nested hierarchy, this is fairly straightforward:

```
public static List<Object> convertAListToBList(List<Object> aList) {
    List<Object> bList = new ArrayList<Object>();

    for (Object obj : aList) {
        if (obj instanceof A) {
            bList.add(convertAToB((A)obj));
        } else if (obj instanceof List) {
            bList.add(convertAListToBList((List<Object>)obj));
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown object in hierarchy");
        }
    }
    return bList;
}
```

However, in the case where there are empty lists it becomes a bit more complicated. For example, if we pass in a `List<List<List<A>>>` containing `{{{a1, a2}, {a3, a4}}, {}}`, then we would get back `{{{b1, b2}, {b3, b4}}, {}}`. Here the second element in the outer list (`{}`) has type `List<List<A>>` in the argument but will actually just have type `List<B>` in the return value. Can you safely cast an empty list from a `List<B>` to a `List<List<B>>`? I don't know, but anyway this kind of "variable-depth" scenario could be resolvable by adding a parameter to the recursive method to track the maximum depth reached and ensuring that all empty lists drill down to the same depth. However, I don't know how one would go about creating the multi-dimensional list even if one did know how many dimensions at runtime. For example, in this case I know at runtime there are two dimensions and I want to create a new `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>` rather than an `ArrayList<Object>` but I don't know how to do that programmatically.

In the case where the maximum depth is never reached it becomes even more complicated. For example, if I pass in an object of type `List<List<A>>` which just contains `{}`, then I would get back an object of type simply `List<B>` containing `{}`. I don't know if there is even any way to know how many dimensions were in the original list and create an appropriate type.

Am I worrying too much because all this stuff will be erased at runtime anyway?

Summary:

- Can an empty `List<B>` be cast to `List<List<B>>`?
- Is there anyway to find out the number of dimensions of a multi-dimensional empty list?
- Is there any way to return an empty n-dimensional list (i.e. outermost list empty) at runtime given n?
- Will the caller ever have any idea that I returned objects of the "wrong type", due to type erasure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I worrying too much because all this stuff will be erased at runtime anyway?

In a sense, yes - the method you've posted should work just as well with empty lists as with populated lists.  Which isn't to say it will work *well*, but it won't have any more problems than the no-empty-lists case would have.

> Can an empty `List<B>` be cast to `List<List<B>>`?

An empty `List` can always be cast to another generic type, because it doesn't actually contain any values of the type being cast.  **However** this is a bad practice, because you could very well now have two references to your list that think it holds different types, which will cause `ClassCastExceptions` if you ever try to add elements to it.  An *immutable* empty `List`, e.g. [`ImmutableList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) is always safe to cast.

> Is there anyway to find out the number of dimensions of a multi-dimensional empty list?

This doesn't really make sense; an empty list has no dimensions.  Since the generic type is not compiled, there is no way at runtime to know how many dimensions it could have had.

> Is there any way to return an empty n-dimensional list (i.e. outermost list empty) at runtime given n?

No, but again doing so wouldn't be meaningful at runtime.

> the caller ever have any idea that I returned objects of the "wrong type", due to type erasure?

Only if they do something unexpected with the lists, like I alluded to above.  If they pass in a `List<A>` and you cast it and return it as a `List<B>`, they may well insert `B`s into it.  From then on, attempting to interact with the original `List<A>` will raise confusing `ClassCastException`s because there are `B`s in a list that's expected to contain only `A`s.

In short, this pattern is dangerous.  Consider revisiting your requirements, or your implementation.  As is, you're working around the compiler's type safety, which can only lead to problems.

---

> Is there any way to "not" work around the compiler's type-safety when you are dealing with multi-dimensional lists with an unknown number of dimensions?

Without understanding what you're [actually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) trying to do it's difficult to answer your question, but broadly speaking the way to avoid this is to re-examine your requirements, since they're problematic.  The fact that your data has arbitrary depth is strange; can you restructure it so it isn't arbitrarily deep?  Perhaps encode `depth` as an instance variable in `A` and `B` and simply have `List`s of `A` and `B`?

If you really need arbitrary-depth-multi-dimensional data, clearly a `List` isn't the right way to represent that.  You're effectively describing a [Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29), so consider representing it that way (a root node containing a value and a list of nodes).  You might also like Guava's [`Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html).

Comment: Is there any way to "not" work around the compiler's type-safety when you are dealing with multi-dimensional lists with an unknown number of dimensions? There is no such thing as a `List<List<...<List<A>>...>>` kind of type in Java (where the ellipses are literal, similar to variable argument methods). In practice, the reason I am doing this is I am building on an API method which erases such types into just "`Object`" but I don't think their API is necessarily wrong for the same reason just stated.

Comment: PS: when I referred to casting I was only referring to casting by the caller, not casting inside my method. Because I'm returning a `List<Object>`, they may cast it to a `List<List<B>>` thinking that's what it should be, but actually I only returned them a `List<B>`.

Comment: @Kidburla Updated my answer to address your first comment.  An API that erases type information is a bad API.  Regarding your second comment, if your method didn't erase type information callers wouldn't have to deal with guessing.  Whether you do the casting or your callers do, casting a `List` to a different generic type can (and likely will) introduce complicated bugs.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, an empty list (if you're sure that it's empty, and the old alternatively typed reference to this list will not ever be used) can be safely cast to an empty list with any generic type, regardless of compiler warnings, like this:

```
ArrayList<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> l2 = (ArrayList) l1;
```

2) At runtime, there is no such thing as "multi-dimensional empty list".

3) See 2.

4) No. `new ArrayList<A>()` and `new ArrayList<ArrayList<A>>()` and `new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<A>>>()` will return structurally identical objects.